# Height not being set on element using Angular 2 directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create a fluid textarea but I can't get the height to be set on the element when using "the angular 2 way" of doing DOM manipulation.

Component:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[fluidHeight]',
  host: {
    '(input)': 'setHeight()'
  }
})

export class FluidHeightDirective {

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostBinding('style.height.px')
  height: number;

  setHeight() {
    this.height = this._elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

Markup:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="model" fluidHeight></textarea>
```

Why is it that I get the correct value in the `setHeight` function but the height isn't being set on the `textarea`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `.px` in

```
@HostBinding('style.height.px')
```

you should **not** add it here as well

```
this.height = this._elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

Use either

```
@HostBinding('style.height')
```

or

```
    this.height = this._elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Ok it works, any idea why the textarea shrinks on every keystroke until the text reach the height of the textarea and then it starts growing like it's supposed to?

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you please set up a plunker that allows to investigate?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QoZx89rti2xJmD2gS3tU?p=preview I get the opposite effect here though, it grows on every keystroke... Bet it's the same issue though.

Comment: Seems you need to adjust the `scrollHeight`. I set `padding` to `0` and the effect is gone. It's weird that it's different for you locally and in the Plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/i2rihQFDcyYIsJBDaNOX?p=preview. Also setting `height` to `nativeElement.scrollHeight - 4` worked (padding at top and bottom was 2)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the padding in my local setup, because it's bigger than 2. But rather the border... which is annoying and really odd. I'll have to investigate further. Thanks for the help.